# How to block domain from stealing content from my website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I found that someone is stealing all content from my website. I think it's attack on google seo. The problem is that domain uses proxy and his ip is changing every time. http://s75089.com/test.php

How can I block this? Any ideas? Is it possible with htaccess if domain uses proxy?

Comment: Very hard, not really possible in a reliable way. The issue is that you publish information. That means it is freely available, that is the sole purpose of publishing. So the term "stealing" is a bit questionable here... You may want to impose copyright to your content (if you can!). Technically you could try to detect a proxy based on the request headers. Most promising is an approach based on javascript handled tokens, since typically such proxies disable javascript from the content.

Comment: Wow, so there still no way for blocking this? Everyone can be victim of this? You say that information is publish, but as you can see the website is identical and has one target "the google seo". They use my logo etc.

Comment: That is nothing forbidden from a technical and legal point of view, _unless_ there is a copyright violation which you have to go after in a legal way. But another question: what does "target the google seo" actually mean? Why should that harm you?

Comment: They have same content and they still be indexed in google. So my links become worse or someone can open their page and log in then they can steal their password. If their website is identical someone can make an mistake.

Comment: Still not a legal issue, _unless_ they break some copyright or something. Do you have the copyright to your own content? The last questions I saw about topics like this all were from people publishing "stolen" content themselves and then ranted here about other stealing from them...

Comment: If that really is an issue for you, then sue them! Or follow the advice for blocking them which I gave right in my first comment.

Comment: @arkascha I'm looking for solution in code.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am pretty certain that reacting to the request headers or evaluating javascript based tokens _is_ something to be done in code... But maybe you are just looking for a magic button labelled "Keep out those naughty kids!"

Comment: Question: did you even _think_ about actually investigating one of the two technical options I gave you before starting to rant?

Comment: Yes, but they block javascript. And please change your mind because actually you don't bring anything to the subject. Just acting.

Comment: _Exactly_... Do you have any idea how such tokens work?

Comment: Just provide an example if you want to help.

Comment: I certainly _did_ help. If you are not willing to look into what request headers are and how to evaluate them by means of php or if you are not willing to invest some reading into how token based access protection works, then sorry. We are not here to do that for you.

Comment: I wish you good luck and success, this certainly is doable. But you cannot expect someone delivering a solution you can simply copy. Have fun!

Comment: Any link where I can read about this?

Comment: @arkascha if human can access to the website then machine too. I still dont understand how you can fix it by tokens. And they use headers same as googlebot

Comment: Bit of a tip for future questions. Don't insult the single person who is trying to help you. @arkascha offered you a potential solution and you just shrugged it off because it is not as easy as clicking 'block'. He's provided you with some legitamte options.

Comment: @thickguru I did not insult anyone, I found that all the proxies IP's are form proxy-daily.com Maybe is there a way to block all Ip's from this website? If someone feel be insulted then just sorry... boys. It's not my target to insulting here.

Comment: A javascript based access token works such that you inject some unique token generating (or defining) code into a web site which is anchored such in the client side logic that it will be sent back along with all requests to that site. A side not executing the client side logic will contain that token. And a copied site will contain a stale token not valid any more. Both are easy to implement indications when you want to block further access inside a given session.